# Xubuntu overheating on MacbookPro

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, power-management, overheating

I installed Xubuntu 16.04 (64Bit) on my MacBook Pro Unibody Mid 2012.
I also have OS X 10.10.5 installed. It is getting ridiculously hot. I mean, really. Its freaking hot. I couldn't even touch it. Running OS X nothing gets hot!

However, I did not realize that it gets hot. I installed the Linux distribution on it, worked a little with it and then closed the lit, put the computer in my backpack and left it there for over 2hrs. 
When I took the MacBook out of the bag, the bag was hot, the computer was hot, everything was hot. It even smelled a little like plastic and burned. I opened the computer immediately, disconnected the battery (I thought whatever is producing heat there needs to stop) and let it cool down. However, the battery was completely drained. I couldn't start the computer without connecting it to the power plug. I assume that when I closed the lit, the computer (running Xubuntu at this time) did not do into sleeping mode and kept on running until it

a) shut down because it got too hot or

b) the battery was empty.

However, the empty battery indicates that it did not shut down because of overheating, but only because the battery was empty.

1. Why is it getting hot and how do I stop it?
2. Could the computer be damaged? Does Xubuntu on a MacBook Pro shut down when the machine gets too hot, or was it the empty battery that caused the shut down. If it was the empty battery, and the computer is connected to the a power plug *and* it keeps on getting hotter – this is a severe security issue. The computer could start burning or gets damaged or whatever.

Anyone knows something?

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
-k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core 
processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output